# User details stored in separate table ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, web, identity

I am a complete beginner at ASP.net(and this forum) i am using Visual studio 2013 and have created created another table in the created database using the package manager console.

How do i go about placing the information into this new table? (I am looking to store firstname and last name in a separate table)

The create account button is below:

```
Protected Sub CreateUser_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim userName As String = UserNameCtrl.Text
Dim Firstnane As String = firstnamectrl.Text
Dim manager = New UserManager
Dim User = New ApplicationUser() With {.UserName = userName}
Dim result = manager.Create(User, Password.Text)
If result.Succeeded Then

IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, User, isPersistent:=False)
IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
Else
ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()
End If



End Sub
```

Any pointers in the right direction, hints or suggested reading would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this link may be of some help:

http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_database/adonet/article.php/c15033/A-Basic-VBNET-ADONET-Tutorial-Adding-Deleting-and-Updating.htm

It is for a windows form application, but it should translate pretty well if you're using web forms. Basically, you just want to make a connection to the database during the button click event (the simplest way I know of to make this connection is using ADO.NET), and pass the values of the first and last name in a SQL query to the sql server.

You would be building the sql query as a string, and concatenating your vb variables into that string. Something like; "Insert into table xxx(firstname, LastName) values " & Firstname & ", " & Lastname...

Comment: Thanks thats great. Since i am still using the exisitng tabels to hold the username and passwords manager.Create(User, Password.Text) hoe do i get the unique ID to insert into my new table to link.               Can i use SCOPE_IDENTITY even though i am not using an insert command to insert the username and password? Thanks